# Creating contingency table from matrix

Tags: r

I have a matrix like so:

```
       country cLabel
  [1,]       3      1
  [2,]       6      2
  [3,]       8      1
  [4,]       5      2
  [5,]       5      2
  [6,]       8      2
  [7,]       8      2
  [8,]       8      2
  [9,]       8      2
 [10,]       4      2
 [11,]       6      2
 [12,]       3      2
 [13,]       5      2
 [14,]       5      1
```

`country` is a value of 1-8, and `cLabel` is a value of 1-2. How can I print the contingency table for this? I tried `print(table(myMatrix))`.

It is printing

```
 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8 
60 277  31  32  83  39  24  44
```

and what I want is it to print each country value (1-8) and how many 1s and 2s there are for each of these 8 values.

Comment: `table(as.data.frame(myMatrix))`. why is it being stored as a matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there is a duplicate somewhere.

```
# Turn your matrix into a data.frame, easier to manipulate and to create labels
myDataFrame <- as.data.frame(myMatrix)

# Add factors to coutry, from 1 to 8. This will add missing levels to the final result
myDataFrame$country <- factor(myDataFrame$country, 1:8)

# Table
table(myDataFrame)
#        cLabel
# country 1 2
#       1 0 0
#       2 0 0
#       3 1 1
#       4 0 1
#       5 1 3
#       6 0 2
#       7 0 0
#       8 1 4
```