# Constructing contingency tables including transitions that do not occur

Tags: r

I have a shuffled sequence of behaviours from a list constructed from my data. From this list of behaviours I want to create a contingency table with each transition from one step in the sequence to the next. Once I have this table, I want compare this to my real observed data. Basically comparing one contingency table to another. I have come across a problem where if there is one behaviour state that occurs only once, and happens to be randomly assigned to the first position, my contingency table does not contain one column or row (as the transition from a behaviour to that one does not occur). Then the arrays are non-conformable e.g. observed contingency table to shuffled contingency table.

example

```
    Pbehav1<- 0.9
    Pbehav2<- 0.1
    Pbehav3<- 0
    Pbehav4<- 0
    Pbehav5<- 0
    Pbehav6<-0
    Pbehav7<-0
    Pbehav8<-0
    Pbehav9<-0
    Pbehav10<-0

    Trans<-10

      Behavno<-2

      behaviourlist<-c(rep("a", round(Pbehav1*Trans)), rep("b", round(Pbehav2*Trans)), rep("c", round(Pbehav3*Trans)),rep("d", round(Pbehav4*Trans)), rep("e", round(Pbehav5*Trans)), rep("f", round(Pbehav6*Trans)),rep("g", round(Pbehav7*Trans)), rep("h", round(Pbehav8*Trans)), rep("i", round(Pbehav9*Trans)),rep("j", round(Pbehav10*Trans))) 

    random<-sample(behaviourlist)
    random
     [1] "b" "a" "a" "a" "a" "a" "a" "a" "a" "a"
    random1<-random[1:(length(random)-1)]

    random2<-random[2: length(random)]

    shuffledcontingencytable <- table(random1, random2)
    shuffledcontingencytable
           random2
    random1 a
          a 8
          b 1
```

Another shuffle of the behaviourlist is more likely to produce:

```
 shuffledcontingencytable
           random2
    random1 a b
          a 7 1
          b 1 0
```

I need all shuffled contingency tables to contain both rows and columns (determined by the probability of each behaviour occurring --- Pbehav1<- 0.9
        Pbehav2<- 0.1), filled with 0's if a transition does not occur. This is part of loop to compare the shuffled contingency table to an observed (fixed) contingency table.

I'd really appreciate any help, I'm new to R and have been struggling with this for a couple of days.

Thanks!

Comment: You need factors. See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35470685/creating-contingency-table-from-matrix/35471021#35471021

Comment: Thank you Pascal, that works well. I appreciate the help.